# SoapFault The string '' is not a valid Boolean value.' faultactor: 'null' Error

Tags: android, soap, android-ksoap2

When trying to make a request to a webservice from Android app i am getting the error below

> SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'Server was unable to read request. ---> There is an >error in XML document (1, 23053). ---> The string '' is not a valid Boolean value.' faultactor: 'null'

in the code everything looks fine but, i don't understand how is it possible to set a string to boolean without getting any errors. I am successfully able to build the project. How can i spot the problem from this error message?

Comment: Show Your soap xml dump and other things that may be useful to help You.

Comment: Unfortunately it is a commercial project and the Xml is approximately 1000 rows long. I just need some predictions about what can result in a error like this. So i can check.

Comment: I would look for what is declared as boolean but request on android side sets it as fe. empty string, "null", "true" or "false". And i bet "XML document (1, 23053)" means first row, 23053 character - in fact byte 23053 of request.

Answer (score 1):

I face the same issues **not a valid Boolean value** because I was sending tags with no data and service require either true or false but not null. Therefore if the fields have no data better to remove if it's optional.